# Adding axis labels and titles to a simple line graph/chart

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d, java-2d, linegraph

I'm new to Java programming. I have a graph created in java but I want to add a title (e.g. "Variation of Distance with time")and also label the x-axis (e.g. "Time (s)") and y-axis (e.g. "Distance (m)"), with the y-axis rotated through 90 degrees.

How would I achieve that?

The code is given below.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GraphPanel extends JPanel {

private int width = 800;
private int heigth = 400;
private int padding = 25;
private int labelPadding = 25;
private Color lineColor = new Color(44, 102, 230, 180);
private Color pointColor = new Color(100, 100, 100, 180);
private Color gridColor = new Color(200, 200, 200, 200);
private static final Stroke GRAPH_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
private int pointWidth = 4;
private int numberYDivisions = 10;
private List<Double> scores;

public GraphPanel(List<Double> scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,             RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) /     (scores.size() - 1);
    double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

    List<Point> graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        int x1 = (int) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
        int y1 = (int) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
        graphPoints.add(new Point(x1, y1));
    }

    // draw white background
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(padding + labelPadding, padding, getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding, getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // create hatch marks and grid lines for y axis.
    for (int i = 0; i < numberYDivisions + 1; i++) {
        int x0 = padding + labelPadding;
        int x1 = pointWidth + padding + labelPadding;
        int y0 = getHeight() - ((i * (getHeight() - padding * 2 - labelPadding)) / numberYDivisions + padding + labelPadding);
        int y1 = y0;
        if (scores.size() > 0) {
            g2.setColor(gridColor);
            g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding + 1 + pointWidth, y0, getWidth() - padding, y1);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            String yLabel = ((int) ((getMinScore() + (getMaxScore() - getMinScore()) * ((i * 1.0) / numberYDivisions)) * 100)) / 100.0 + "";
            FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
            int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(yLabel);
            g2.drawString(yLabel, x0 - labelWidth - 5, y0 + (metrics.getHeight() / 2) - 3);
        }
        g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    }

    // and for x axis
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        if (scores.size() > 1) {
            int x0 = i * (getWidth() - padding * 2 - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1) + padding + labelPadding;
            int x1 = x0;
            int y0 = getHeight() - padding - labelPadding;
            int y1 = y0 - pointWidth;
            if ((i % ((int) ((scores.size() / 20.0)) + 1)) == 0) {
                g2.setColor(gridColor);
                g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String xLabel = i + "";
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                g2.drawString(xLabel, x0 - labelWidth / 2, y0 + metrics.getHeight() + 3);
            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }
    }

    // create x and y axes 
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);

    Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
        int x1 = graphPoints.get(i).x;
        int y1 = graphPoints.get(i).y;
        int x2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).x;
        int y2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).y;
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
    g2.setColor(pointColor);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size(); i++) {
        int x = graphPoints.get(i).x - pointWidth / 2;
        int y = graphPoints.get(i).y - pointWidth / 2;
        int ovalW = pointWidth;
        int ovalH = pointWidth;
        g2.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
    }
}
//    @Override
//    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
//        return new Dimension(width, heigth);
//    }
private double getMinScore() {
    double minScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Double score : scores) {
        minScore = Math.min(minScore, score);
    }
    return minScore;
}

private double getMaxScore() {
    double maxScore = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Double score : scores) {
        maxScore = Math.max(maxScore, score);
    }
    return maxScore;
}

public void setScores(List<Double> scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
    invalidate();
    this.repaint();
}

public List<Double> getScores() {
    return scores;
}

private static void createAndShowGui() {
    List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int maxDataPoints = 40;
    int maxScore = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxDataPoints; i++) {
        scores.add((double) random.nextDouble() * maxScore);
//            scores.add((double) i);
    }
    GraphPanel mainPanel = new GraphPanel(scores);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
     }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: For the title, create a TitledBorder (these lines of code right after `JPanel mainPanel = new GraphPanel(scores);`)  : `TitledBorder title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 10), "Variation of Distance with time");` --- `title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);` --- `title.setTitleFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));` --- `mainPanel.setBorder(title);` (If this is what you mean with "title")

Comment: @LuxxMiner, yes that worked. But is it possible to set the title outside the main method? As I am actually passing an instance of the graph to a JOptionPane thus the title does not show up. Thanks!

Comment: @VictorMenta Just to the same thing in the cunstructor of the panel, but remove the `mainPanel.` at `mainPanel.setBorder(title);`.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, How?

Comment: @LuxxMiner, it worked, thanks! How about the axes labels?

Comment: @VictorMenta I don't think you can do this with borders too. Maybe you should have seperate 4 panels inside another panel - One for the `Graphpanel`, one for the title, two for the axis labels.  (I will post an example) I don't know if there's a better way to do it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

public MainPanel(List<Double> scores) {

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel title = new JLabel("Variation of Distance with time");
    title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
    title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

    JPanel graphPanel = new GraphPanel(scores);

    MainPanel.VerticalPanel vertPanel = new MainPanel.VerticalPanel();

    MainPanel.HorizontalPanel horiPanel = new MainPanel.HorizontalPanel();

    add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(horiPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(vertPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(graphPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

class VerticalPanel extends JPanel {

    public VerticalPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 0));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
        gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

        String string = "Time (s)";

        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
        int height = metrics.getHeight();

        gg.setFont(font);

        drawRotate(gg, getWidth(), (getHeight() + width) / 2, 270, string);
    }

    public void drawRotate(Graphics2D gg, double x, double y, int angle, String text) {
        gg.translate((float) x, (float) y);
        gg.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
        gg.drawString(text, 0, 0);
        gg.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle));
        gg.translate(-(float) x, -(float) y);
    }

}

class HorizontalPanel extends JPanel {

    public HorizontalPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
        gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

        String string = "Distance (m)";

        FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
        int height = metrics.getHeight();

        gg.setFont(font);

        gg.drawString(string, (getWidth() - width) / 2, 11);
    }

}

static class GraphPanel extends JPanel {
//    private List<Double> scores;

    private int width = 800;
    private int heigth = 400;
    private int padding = 25;
    private int labelPadding = 25;
    private Color lineColor = new Color(44, 102, 230, 180);
    private Color pointColor = new Color(100, 100, 100, 180);
    private Color gridColor = new Color(200, 200, 200, 200);
    private static final Stroke GRAPH_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
    private int pointWidth = 4;
    private int numberYDivisions = 10;
    private List<Double> scores;

    public GraphPanel(List<Double> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
        double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

        List<Point> graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            int x1 = (int) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
            int y1 = (int) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
            graphPoints.add(new Point(x1, y1));
        }

        // draw white background
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(padding + labelPadding, padding, getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding, getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // create hatch marks and grid lines for y axis.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberYDivisions + 1; i++) {
            int x0 = padding + labelPadding;
            int x1 = pointWidth + padding + labelPadding;
            int y0 = getHeight() - ((i * (getHeight() - padding * 2 - labelPadding)) / numberYDivisions + padding + labelPadding);
            int y1 = y0;
            if (scores.size() > 0) {
                g2.setColor(gridColor);
                g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding + 1 + pointWidth, y0, getWidth() - padding, y1);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String yLabel = ((int) ((getMinScore() + (getMaxScore() - getMinScore()) * ((i * 1.0) / numberYDivisions)) * 100)) / 100.0 + "";
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(yLabel);
                g2.drawString(yLabel, x0 - labelWidth - 5, y0 + (metrics.getHeight() / 2) - 3);
            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }

        // and for x axis
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            if (scores.size() > 1) {
                int x0 = i * (getWidth() - padding * 2 - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1) + padding + labelPadding;
                int x1 = x0;
                int y0 = getHeight() - padding - labelPadding;
                int y1 = y0 - pointWidth;
                if ((i % ((int) ((scores.size() / 20.0)) + 1)) == 0) {
                    g2.setColor(gridColor);
                    g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    String xLabel = i + "";
                    FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                    int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                    g2.drawString(xLabel, x0 - labelWidth / 2, y0 + metrics.getHeight() + 3);
                }
                g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
            }
        }

        // create x and y axes 
        g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
        g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);

        Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setColor(lineColor);
        g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
            int x1 = graphPoints.get(i).x;
            int y1 = graphPoints.get(i).y;
            int x2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).x;
            int y2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).y;
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
        g2.setColor(pointColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size(); i++) {
            int x = graphPoints.get(i).x - pointWidth / 2;
            int y = graphPoints.get(i).y - pointWidth / 2;
            int ovalW = pointWidth;
            int ovalH = pointWidth;
            g2.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
//        return new Dimension(width, heigth);
//    }
    private double getMinScore() {
        double minScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Double score : scores) {
            minScore = Math.min(minScore, score);
        }
        return minScore;
    }

    private double getMaxScore() {
        double maxScore = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Double score : scores) {
            maxScore = Math.max(maxScore, score);
        }
        return maxScore;
    }

    public void setScores(List<Double> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
        invalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public List<Double> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(width, heigth);
    }

    class VerticalPanel extends JPanel {

        public VerticalPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
            gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

            String string = "Time (s)";

            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
            int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
            int height = metrics.getHeight();

            gg.setFont(font);

            drawRotate(gg, getWidth(), (getHeight() + width) / 2, 270, string);
        }

        public void drawRotate(Graphics2D gg, double x, double y, int angle, String text) {
            gg.translate((float) x, (float) y);
            gg.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
            gg.drawString(text, 0, 0);
            gg.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle));
            gg.translate(-(float) x, -(float) y);
        }

    }

    class HorizontalPanel extends JPanel {

        public HorizontalPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
            gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

            String string = "Distance (m)";

            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
            int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
            int height = metrics.getHeight();

            gg.setFont(font);

            gg.drawString(string, (getWidth() - width) / 2, 11);
        }

    }

}

}
```

The calling method will be something like:

```
public void btnPlotActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
MainPanel daGraph = new MainPanel(plotValues);
    Object option[] = {" Exit "};
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(this, daGraph, "Distance-Time Graph", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, option, null);
}
```

Comment: If this is the correct answer, please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) your answer, so people see this was the solution :)

Answer (score 3):

I'll have to give you a cheeky but working answer. I couldn't manage to rotate a JLabel, so I decided the easiest way would be to just draw the String... (My excuse: You also *draw* the Strings in the graph, so this would "match" better ;) ) The class `MainPanel` contains 4 seperate panels: One for the title, one for each axis and one for the `GraphPanel`. Visualization:

[image]

Full code:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GraphPanel extends JPanel {

    private int width = 800;
    private int heigth = 400;
    private int padding = 25;
    private int labelPadding = 25;
    private Color lineColor = new Color(44, 102, 230, 180);
    private Color pointColor = new Color(100, 100, 100, 180);
    private Color gridColor = new Color(200, 200, 200, 200);
    private static final Stroke GRAPH_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
    private int pointWidth = 4;
    private int numberYDivisions = 10;
    private List<Double> scores;

    public GraphPanel(List<Double> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
        double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

        List<Point> graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            int x1 = (int) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
            int y1 = (int) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
            graphPoints.add(new Point(x1, y1));
        }

        // draw white background
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(padding + labelPadding, padding, getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding,
                getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // create hatch marks and grid lines for y axis.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberYDivisions + 1; i++) {
            int x0 = padding + labelPadding;
            int x1 = pointWidth + padding + labelPadding;
            int y0 = getHeight()
                    - ((i * (getHeight() - padding * 2 - labelPadding)) / numberYDivisions + padding + labelPadding);
            int y1 = y0;
            if (scores.size() > 0) {
                g2.setColor(gridColor);
                g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding + 1 + pointWidth, y0, getWidth() - padding, y1);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String yLabel = ((int) ((getMinScore()
                        + (getMaxScore() - getMinScore()) * ((i * 1.0) / numberYDivisions)) * 100)) / 100.0 + "";
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(yLabel);
                g2.drawString(yLabel, x0 - labelWidth - 5, y0 + (metrics.getHeight() / 2) - 3);
            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }

        // and for x axis
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            if (scores.size() > 1) {
                int x0 = i * (getWidth() - padding * 2 - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1) + padding + labelPadding;
                int x1 = x0;
                int y0 = getHeight() - padding - labelPadding;
                int y1 = y0 - pointWidth;
                if ((i % ((int) ((scores.size() / 20.0)) + 1)) == 0) {
                    g2.setColor(gridColor);
                    g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    String xLabel = i + "";
                    FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                    int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                    g2.drawString(xLabel, x0 - labelWidth / 2, y0 + metrics.getHeight() + 3);
                }
                g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
            }
        }

        // create x and y axes
        g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
        g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding,
                getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);

        Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setColor(lineColor);
        g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
            int x1 = graphPoints.get(i).x;
            int y1 = graphPoints.get(i).y;
            int x2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).x;
            int y2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).y;
            g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }

        g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
        g2.setColor(pointColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size(); i++) {
            int x = graphPoints.get(i).x - pointWidth / 2;
            int y = graphPoints.get(i).y - pointWidth / 2;
            int ovalW = pointWidth;
            int ovalH = pointWidth;
            g2.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
        }
    }

    // @Override
    // public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    // return new Dimension(width, heigth);
    // }
    private double getMinScore() {
        double minScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Double score : scores) {
            minScore = Math.min(minScore, score);
        }
        return minScore;
    }

    private double getMaxScore() {
        double maxScore = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Double score : scores) {
            maxScore = Math.max(maxScore, score);
        }
        return maxScore;
    }

    public void setScores(List<Double> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
        invalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public List<Double> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxDataPoints = 40;
        int maxScore = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxDataPoints; i++) {
            scores.add((double) random.nextDouble() * maxScore);
            // scores.add((double) i);
        }
        MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(scores);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

    //Main changes underneath

    static class MainPanel extends JPanel {

        public MainPanel(List<Double> scores) {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JLabel title = new JLabel("Variation of Distance with time");
            title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
            title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

            JPanel graphPanel = new GraphPanel(scores);

            VerticalPanel vertPanel = new VerticalPanel();

            HorizontalPanel horiPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

            add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(horiPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            add(vertPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(graphPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }

        class VerticalPanel extends JPanel {

            public VerticalPanel() {
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 0));
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
                gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

                String string = "Time (s)";

                FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
                int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
                int height = metrics.getHeight();

                gg.setFont(font);

                drawRotate(gg, getWidth(), (getHeight() + width) / 2, 270, string);
            }

            public void drawRotate(Graphics2D gg, double x, double y, int angle, String text) {
                gg.translate((float) x, (float) y);
                gg.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
                gg.drawString(text, 0, 0);
                gg.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle));
                gg.translate(-(float) x, -(float) y);
            }

        }

        class HorizontalPanel extends JPanel {

            public HorizontalPanel() {
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));
            }

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                super.paintComponent(g);

                Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
                gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

                String string = "Distance (m)";

                FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
                int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
                int height = metrics.getHeight();

                gg.setFont(font);

                gg.drawString(string, (getWidth() - width) / 2, 11);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Pic of the working program (Keep in mind that the title is centered relative to the width of the whole panel, not the graph):

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to pass the graph as an object to a JOptionPane and so the main() method will not be called. I have restructured your code to suit my needs, it's posted below.